# How do I display a block matching page and content type criteria?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-7

I have some Views which display specific content types.

On these views I want to display a block containing a menu.

What I have found is that I can restrict the block containing the menu to certain pages and include the views in those pages, and this works fine but when a user clicks on the teaser through to the actual article it is no longer in the page list and so doesn't display the menu.

I can also restrict the menu block to specific content types in which case the situation is reversed i.e. it displays on the page containing the node (because it is of the content type) but not on the page containing the view.

Is there a way I can display a block so that it meets both a specific page criteria and a content type criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly... In the block's configuration page you can choose which pages to show the block.  If your content type was *article*, and your view was a *page display* with a path of `path/to/view`, you could use settings like this:

[image: Block configuration]

Comment: Hi Laxman, I don't see a content type in any of my urls so a specific node will have the format sitename/node/nodenumber e.g. mysite/node/34 .

Comment: You could add the pathauto module, with this you can create custom url aliases for different content types, users, etc: http://drupal.org/project/pathauto

Comment: That's just the job laxman. What a great module pathauto is. Many thanks.